# Transform Object to Array and sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, transform

I have a javascript object which looks like the following:

```
{ john:32, elizabeth: 29, kevin: 30 }
```

This is an object with some names and ages.

How can I transform the object to array and sort the array by age?

I want it to be something like `[{john:32}, {elizabeth:29}....]`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like the output array to look like?

Comment: Sorry about that I wanted to be something like [{john:32},{elizabeth:29}....]

Comment: Sorry dev_junwen but because I am new to js can you explain your answer a lit bit more.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `Object.entries` to convert the object to an array, then use the array `sort` method to do the sorting, and then `reduce` to reformat the array. See below.

```js
const people = { john:32, elizabeth:29, kevin:30 };

const sorted = Object.entries(people).sort(
  (a, b) => a[1] - b[1]
).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  acc.push({[key]: val});
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: You are genious. Thank you. I was really struggling with this. I will upvote you.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

## 1 line solution

```js
console.log( Object.values({john:32, elizabeth:29, kevin:30}).sort((a, b)=>a - b) )
```

## If you want array of objects

```js
const obj = { john: 32, elizabeth: 29, kevin: 30 }

console.log(
    Object.keys(obj)
    .map(key=>({[key]: obj[key]}))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` to loop over the object keys to calculate the final result.

```js
let peopleObject = {john: 32, elizabeth: 29, kevin: 30};
let result = Object.keys(peopleObject).reduce((rs, el) => {return [...rs, {[el]: peopleObject[el]}]; }, []).sort((a,b) =>Object.values(a)[0] - Object.values(b)[0])
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//declaration
var myArray = [];
var myObject = {john:32, elizabeth:29, kevin:30};

//pushing the object in to an array
for (var key in myObject) {
     myArray.push([key, myObject[key ]]);
}

//sorting function
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a[1] - b[1];
});

//the above function returns the sorted array as
//elizabeth,29,kevin,30,john,32


//to create the sorted object from array
var objSorted = {}
myArray.forEach(function(item){
  objSorted[item[0]]=item[1]
});

//final output
//{elizabeth: 29, john: 32, kevin: 30}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case

```js
var obj = { john:32, elizabeth:29, kevin:30 };

    var rs = Object.keys(obj).reduce((rs, el) => {let b= {}; b[el] = obj[el];rs.push(b); return rs; }, []).sort((a,b) =>Object.values(a)[0] - Object.values(b)[0])
    console.log(rs)
```